# Why do I keep getting 'undefined' for each item in this JSON array?

Tags: jquery, json

The following is returning 'undefined' as the value for each item.  Can someone show me why?

Jquery

```
    $("button").click(function () {
    var estimateID = this.id;
    var baseURL = "/Dashboard/EstimateDetails/";
    var url = baseURL + estimateID;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.details.length; i++) {
            $('#Details').html("<p>item1=" + data.details.Dma + " item2=" + data.details.Callsign + " item3=" + data.details.Description + "</p>");
        }
    });
```

JSON

```
{
    "details": [{
        "Dma": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy",
        "CallSign": "WRGB",
        "Description": "WRGB (CBS) Schenectady"
    }, {
        "Dma": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy",
        "CallSign": "WTEN",
        "Description": "WTEN (ABC) Albany "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy",
        "CallSign": "WXXA",
        "Description": "WXXA (Fox) Albany "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Atlanta",
        "CallSign": "WGCL",
        "Description": "WGCL (CBS) Atlanta "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Atlanta",
        "CallSign": "WXIA",
        "Description": "WXIA (NBC) Atlanta "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Austin",
        "CallSign": "KXAN",
        "Description": "KXAN (NBC) Austin "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Austin",
        "CallSign": "KVUE",
        "Description": "KVUE (ABC) Austin "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Baltimore",
        "CallSign": "WMAR",
        "Description": "WMAR (ABC) Baltimore "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Baltimore",
        "CallSign": "WBAL",
        "Description": "WBAL (NBC) Baltimore"
    }, {
        "Dma": "Baltimore",
        "CallSign": "WJZ ",
        "Description": "WJZ  (CBS) Baltimore "
    }, {
        "Dma": "Baltimore",
        "CallSign": "WBFF",
        "Description": "WBFF (Fox) Baltimore "
    }]
}
```

EDIT - the result when I run the above code is a single line of HTML added to the details div as follows:

`item1=undefined item2=undefined item3=undefined`

Comment: You should totally drop that and use `data.details[i].Dma + " item2=" + data.details[i].Callsign + " item3=" + data.details[i].Description` instead. Also `.html` doesn't make any sense there.

Comment: Good catch.  I should use .append instead of .html. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.details.Callsign` is wrong

`data.details[i].Callsign`

is what you want, i.e. you are missing the array index as you loop over `details`.  Notice you are doing that for multiple variables.

Cleaner code might help. Separating the variables out like so is a good start...

```
 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
     var details = data.details,
         dma, callSign,...; // and the rest of whatever you need

     for (var i = 0; i <= details.length; i++) {
         dma      = details[i].Dma;
         callSign = details[i].Callsign;
         // more here

         $('#Details').html("<p>item1=" + dma + " item2=" + callSign + ...
     }            
 });
```

Is much more readable, and less error prone IMHO.

EDIT -- as pointed out in comments, `html` will overwrite the content of your div each time in the loop.  You probably want `append` instead.

Comment: I think this should incorporate Esailija's comment above.  I should not have used .html because it results only the last line appearing in the div (I think each line is writing over the preceding).  Instead .append seems more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You left off the array index in your loop.

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var estimateID = this.id;
    var baseURL = "/Dashboard/EstimateDetails/";
    var url = baseURL + estimateID;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.details.length; i++) {
            $('#Details').html("<p>item1=" + data.details[i].Dma + " item2=" + data.details[i].Callsign + " item3=" + data.details[i].Description + "</p>");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `details` as an array, therefore you need to index it to access its members. In the for loop, for example, you want this type of thing:

```
data.details[i].Dma
```

instead of

```
data.details.Dma
```

By the way, you *could* use a jQuery each callback instead of a for loop:

```
if (data && data.details) {
    $.each(data.details, function() {
            $('#Details').html("<p>item1=" + this.Dma + " item2=" + this.Callsign +
                " item3=" + this.Description + "</p>");
        });
}
```

Within the callback function passed to each, `this` stands in for `data.details[i]` in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't familiar with that approach.  Just learned something new.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Use

`data.details[i].Dma` etc

Also add `-1` in the loop `data.details.length-1`, because index starts with `0`.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= data.details.length-1; i++) {
  $('#Details').html("<p>item1=" + data.details[i].Dma + " item2=" + data.details[i].Callsign + " item3=" + data.details[i].Description + "</p>");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aqPvL/

Comment: Good point about adding '-1'.  Although strangely I get the same output with or without it.  +1

Comment: @hughesdan Thanks for +1 for -1 :P

Answer (score 0):

inside the for loop you need to reference your objects via `data.details[i]`

for example

```
data.details[i].Callsign
```

not

```
data.details.Callsign
```

Answer (score 0):

add the index to the end of data.details

`data.details.Dma` becomes `data.details[i].Dma`